# How to pass named params to powershell script using Terraform local-exec?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to figure out the proper way to pass named arguments to my powershell script using terraform local-exec.

Do I need to quote delimit params in this case like so?

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "powershell -file ../BindCert.ps1 -certString '${var.cert_string_b64}' -certPassword '${var.cert_password}' -certThumbprint '${var.cert_thumbprint}' -certName '${var.cert_name}'"
  }
```

Windows 10
Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your issue, you can change the code like below:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "powershell -file ../BindCert.ps1 -certString ${var.cert_string_b64} -certPassword ${var.cert_password} -certThumbprint ${var.cert_thumbprint} -certName ${var.cert_name}"
    }
```

I will show you the test which I did on my side.

PowerShell script:

```
param([String]$rgName = "rgName")
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgName
```

Terraform code:

```
variable "test" {
    type = "string"
    default = "charles"
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "PowerShell -file ./test.ps1 -rgName ${var.test}"
    }
}
```

The screenshot of the result:

[image]

For more details, see [Terraform local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html).

Comment: Thanks ... That works well until a string param value has embedded space like 'West US' for arm location.

Comment: @user2368632 you can use "westus"

Comment: @user2368632 You can specified as -region 'West US' which is fined